# Ошибка "; expected", ") expected", "Unchecked call to ArrayAdapter"

Tags: java, android

Есть 3 ошибки

```
public class Gadgets_activity extends AppCompatActivity  {
ListView Gadget_list;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gadgets_activity);

    Gadget_list = findViewById(R.id.Gadget_list);

    String[] Gadget = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gadget);
    // ошибка " Unchecked call to ArrayAdapter(Context,int,T[]) as a member of raw type "Android.widget.ArrayAdapter""

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Gadget);

    Gadget_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Gadget_list.setOnItemClickListener 
            (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(Gadgets_activity.this, Discription_activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title", position);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
// Возле следующей скобки ошибка ") expected"
            }
// Возле следующей скобки ошибка "; expected"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну попробуйте так

```
Gadget_list.setOnItemClickListener 
        (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(Gadgets_activity.this, Discription_activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```